# Paused flow interviews vs time-based workflow

Tags: workflow, visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow

Do paused flow interviews and time-based workflow process in parallel?
each can process 1000 records per hour. if I have 1000 paused flow interviews and 1000 time-based workflow actions scheduled to happen at the same hour do they both happen in parallel?

Couldn't find clear information in the docs so any info here will be appreciated